# Linq to Lucene error: "Classes must define at least one field as a default search field"

Tags: c#, linq, search, lucene

I have the following attributes applied to my linq to sql class:

```
[Document(MetadataType = typeof(SomeObjectMetadata))]
public partial class SomeObject
{
}
```

And this is the metadata code:

```
public class SomeObjectMetadata
{

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes, IsKey = true)]  
    private object ProductId { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes, IsDefault = true)]  
    private object Name { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]  
    private object Description { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Breadcrumb { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Tab1Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Tab2Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Tab3Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Tab4Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Tab5Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)] 
    private object Manufacturer { get; set; }

}
```

The index store writes just fine, but when I try to search it, I get the error shown in the title.  Here's an example search:

```
        var qry = from r in _dbi.Get<SomeObject>()
                  where r.Description.Like(search)
                  select r;
```

Upon enumerating "qry", the Exception "Classes must define at least one field as a default search field" is thrown.

Comment: should I delete such an idiot question?

Comment: I would.  And... I'm not the one that downvoted you. :)

Comment: Maybe this will allow someone who made the same mistake to find an answer ;o)

Comment: Downvotes well deserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I'm an idiot.  The metadata fields were private.  This fixes it, of course:

```
public class Catalog_ProductMetadata
{

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes, IsKey = true)]
    public object ProductId { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes, IsDefault = true)]
    public object Name { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Description { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Breadcrumb { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Tab1Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Tab2Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Tab3Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Tab4Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Tab5Content { get; set; }

    [Field(FieldIndex.Tokenized, FieldStore.Yes)]
    public object Manufacturer { get; set; }

}
```